# Removing 'Back' button

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using React-Navigation and I'm having trouble with the navigation bar.
I have a page called LoginScreen which moves the user to the HomeScreen after logging in.
The problem I have is that I have a 'back' button in the homescreen so I can go back to the loginscreen (which I don't want) this is the code:

LoginScreen (where I navigate to the home screen):

```
handlePress(navigate){
    firebaseRef.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then(function(firebaseUser){
      //Success, move to homepage.
      navigate("Home");
    }).catch(function(error){
      //Failed to log in, print error.
    });
}
```

navigate is inside `render()`:

```
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
```

this is where I call handlePress:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.logBtn} onPress={()=>this.handlePress(navigate)}>
  <Text style={styles.logTxt}>
  Login
  </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

I searched a little and tried writing `navigate.replace("Home");` in `handlePress` but it just won't navigate then.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best thing for you to do is to reset the navigation which you can do with the reset:

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';


    const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      actions: [
        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home'})
      ]
    })
    this.props.navigation.dispatch.(resetAction);
```

You can find this or read more about it here [react-navigation-doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions)

or you can change the back button icon with its function in your HomeScreen navigation configuration

```
static navigationOptions  = {
        title: 'Home',
        header: ({ navigate }) => {
        {/* left here refers to the left back button */}
            let left = (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigate('Profile')} >
                    <Icon name="ios-menu-outline"
                    size={25} style={{ paddingRight: 5, paddingLeft: 20 }}
                    color="#ffffff" />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            );
            let style = { backgroundColor: '#00AFEF',elevation: 0,shadowOpacity: 0,};
            let titleStyle = { color: '#ffff', fontSize: 25, fontFamily: 'Arial' };
            return { left, style, titleStyle }
        },
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static navigationOptions={
    title:'Categories',
    headerLeft: (<View></View>),   };
```

Works for me ;)